# How to show part of the Fragment under the TabLayout

Tags: android, xml

I managed to crate "dots" Tab layout using the below codes:

`layout.xml`:

```
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        app:tabGravity="center"
        app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`tab_selector.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_selected"
        android:state_selected="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_indicator_default"/>
</selector>
```

`tab_indicator_default.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="2dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

`tab_indicator_selected`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="0dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="4dp"
            android:useLevel="false">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

For buttons styling, I used:

```
<style name="PrimaryFlatButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

and called it as:

```
android:theme="@style/PrimaryFlatButton"
```

but  noticed the lower part of the tabs is always above the TabLayout.

I need to be able to show `textView` or `Button` as below, what shall I do or change in the above (or ant where else) to get it this way?

[image]

**UPDATE**

What I'm getting so far is:

[image]

Comment: I am not getting what you want... Do you want your tabs on top of fragments as tab is at bottom now as on top of screen ?

Comment: can you please attach complete screenshot what u have right now and if its possible then design or screenshot of what u want it to b ?

Comment: ok what do you want now ? You want it to b like first screenshot ?

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan, Yes, I want it to be like the first screen

Comment: you want skip and next button on sides of tablayout and tablayout in center ?

Comment: ok give me 5 mins to review your code :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan OK :)

Comment: https://github.com/romandanylyk/PageIndicatorView try this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="bottom">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
            app:tabGravity="center"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Make it like this it will do the job you wanted :) Hope it helps Best of Luck ! Happy Coding :)
[image: Here is outcome]

Comment: you can add your buttons/textviews/imageviews here where I created two buttons. Then on any fragment by on click listener implement what you want these buttons to do by passing context.

Comment: Hope it helps :)

Comment: I think same issue will be there because of viewpager's height is match_parent(so you get view pager will be full screen) where as you have to pass height =0 and weight = 1.

Comment: I just wrote that code in android studio and watched the output. It works fine

Comment: Thanks, but here you are changing the `layout` file itself, what if I want to have some thing different in the first and the last taps, like the first one, not to show `SKIP`and show next instead of the arrow, and the last one to show `DONE` instead of the arrow!

Comment: you can change the text of buttons or imageviews dynamically when you are on fragment there you can call the button and change the text of button or image view respectively you can also show hide on specific fragments dynamically as per your requirement :) Good Luck!  :)

Comment: Sure it helped a lot, thanks, now I've to figure out how to customize the button text based on the selected page.

Comment: Can you spend another 5 minutes with this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43675161/2441637 :)